# how to add color strip under button icon?

Tags: android, jquery, ios, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I want to add a little color strip under a button icon when the button is selected on a android and iOS app. I'm using cordova so all the UI is done in html/css using bootstrap, jquery, and font awesome.

```
<button id="settings" class="mtt-navbar-item">
  <div class="colorstrip-inactive" id="settings_strip">
    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
  </div>
</button>

css classes:
.colorstrip-active{border-bottom:5px solid #287972;}
.colorstrip-inactive{border-bottom:5px solid #cccccc;}
```

I'm trying to change the color of the strip by calling this:

```
$('#settings_strip').removeClass('colorstrip-inactive').addClass('colorstrip-active');
```

But after doing research, apparently divs inside buttons are illegal. So that doesn't work. Anyone with any solution to get around this?

Comment: seems to work fine : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/1qnok117/ . What are you expecting ?

Comment: doesn't work in chrome and safari for android and iOS, using bootstrap 3.2, jquery 1.9.1